# Policy report to view summary of all resources an account has access on GCloud

Tags: gcloud, policy

In GCloud, I would like to see what resources a service account can access but the console shows me the message `The Selected project does not have any ancestors to run a policy report over`.

Anyone knows what does this mean and how to fix it?

[image: GCloud Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The Policy Analyzer requires an Google Cloud Organization. You can run the Policy Analyzer at the organization or folder level.

If you have an organization, select the Organization at the top of the Google Cloud Console in the project selector dropdown.

If you do not have an organization, create one and move your project into the organization.

Comment: if the project was created without organization merely moving it to the organization doesn't help. GCP royally screwed it up.

Comment: @kikap - I disagree. Using the correct IAM roles solves your problem. You are also commenting on a problem that does not exist in the question. In that case, you should have posted a new question and self-answered it. Please read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/analyze-iam-policies#cloudasset-permissions) first.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on a problem, I was commenting on an answer, if you didn't notice: "If you do not have an organization, create one and move your project into the organization."

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, you need to move the project to the organization, but this alone would not help (although it has to, but Google is Google).
You'll need to "bind" yourself as an owner to the organization:
`gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding <your org id as number>  --member 'user:your@email.com' --role='roles/owner'`
Yes, this is despite the fact that you created the organization and you are the owner of it. You can't understand this, you can only memorize this.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The owner role is not required to run the Policy Analyzer. The roles required is "Cloud Asset Viewer" and "Viewer". [reference](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/analyze-iam-policies#cloudasset-permissions) To use the CLI requires also adding "Service Usage Consumer".

Comment: Wrong or not, but that was the only thing that helped me yesterday, when I finally migrated my "organizationless" account to organization. Fun part was that I did have the organization, but its setup was not completed for whatever reason (it's been years I used this account). Moreover, do not direct your "wrong" at me - this is what Policy Analyzer told me ("Your resource lacks the owner role" or something along these lines).  Sorry about that, @JohnHanley